# Angular 6 Material MatFormField shows as unknown component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, module, angular-material

I am trying to build a basic "blog" with MEAN stack. Now I am trying to work with Angular 6. The console shows this error when load my form page:

> Error: Template parse errors: 'mat-form-field' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. (" [ERROR ->]   "): ng:///AppRoutingModule/CreatePostComponent.html@1:2

I am not sure what is going on... or how to fix it. My code is:

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AngularMaterialModule } from './material';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AngularMaterialModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**material.ts (AngularMaterialModule):**

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';

const modules = [
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatGridListModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatDatepickerModule
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ ...modules ],
  exports: [ ...modules ],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ]
})
export class AngularMaterialModule {}
```

**app-routing.module.ts (created by Angular installation):**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CreatePostComponent } from './posts/create-post.component/create-post.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'posts/new',
    component: CreatePostComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CreatePostComponent
  ],
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**And finally, create-post.component.html:**

```
<form #createPost>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Title">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

So, any comments to help me solve this are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remove the `declarations` in `AppRoutingModule`
2. Add this to `app.module.ts`

   ```
   declarations: [
       AppComponent,
       CreatePostComponent
   ],
   ```
3. Import `AppRoutingModule` to your `AppModule`

   ```
   imports: [ ...modules, AppRoutingModule],
   ```